# Angular 6 Api UI update Issue

Tags: angular

I have been working on the authentication in Angular 6 and for that I have used sessionStorage of Angular.
My issue is that I have a header in which few links are displayed on the basis of the condition that if the user is logged in or not .
So if the user is logged in then he will be able to see only the Logout Button and if he is not logged in then LogIn and Signup Links should be visible.
Now the issue I am facing is when I changed the value of loggedInStatus in typescript function it does not update the html.

Code in the Typescript:

```
onSignOut(){
        sessionStorage.clear();
        alert(sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn'));
        sessionStorage.setItem('loggedIn',false);
        alert(sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn'));
        this.router.navigate(['signin'])
    }
```

Code In the Html:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li *ngIf="authService.isAuthenticated()"><a (click)="onSignOut()">Logout</a></li>
                <ng-template [ngIf]="!authService.isAuthenticated()">
                    <li><a routerLink="/signup">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a routerLink="/signin">Login</a></li>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template [ngIf]="authService.isAuthenticated()">
                <li 
                    class="dropdown"
                    appDropdown>
                    <a style="cursor:pointer" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" >Manage<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a style="cursor:pointer" (click)="onSaveData()">Save Data</a></li>
                        <li><a style="cursor:pointer" (click)="onFetchData()">Fetch Data</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                </ng-template>
            </ul>
```

IsAuthenticated method:

```
isAuthenticated(){
        //return this.token != null;
        return sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn');

    }
```

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Also add the `authService.isAuthenticated()` method to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
[ngIf]="authService.isAuthenticated() == 'false'"
```

Because string will be returned from session storage.

Comment: Thanks it works !!!! But Is that mean only string will be returned and we cannot return a boolean ???

Comment: return sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn') == 'true' if you need to check for a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li *ngIf="!(location.path()!=='/signin' && location.path()!=='/signup')"><a (click)="onSignOut()">Logout</a></li>
            <ng-template *ngIf="location.path()!=='/signin' && location.path()!=='/signup'">
                <li><a routerLink="/signup">Register</a></li>
                <li><a routerLink="/signin">Login</a></li>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template *ngIf="location.path()!=='/signin' && location.path()!=='/signup'">
            <li 
                class="dropdown"
                appDropdown>
                <a style="cursor:pointer" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" >Manage<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a style="cursor:pointer" (click)="onSaveData()">Save Data</a></li>
                    <li><a style="cursor:pointer" (click)="onFetchData()">Fetch Data</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ng-template>
        </ul>
```

Typescript:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location){}
```

try this code for display/hide your item as per your current route path.